# Exception thrown at 0x1000A456 (glut32.dll) OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, exception, glut

When I run my program shows this error, you would know tell me what is the problem? And how can I fix it?

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "Rect.h"

const int rows = 40;
const int cols = 20;
const int length = rows * cols;
int width = 905;
int height = 720;
Rect * list[length];

void createList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        list[i] = new Rect();
    }
}

void createQuad(int index) {
    int wQuad = (width / 20) - 5;
    int hQuad = 12;
    int margin = 5;
    int marginTop = (index / 20) * (hQuad + margin) + margin;
    int marginLeft = (index % 20) * (wQuad + margin) + margin;

    if (list[index]->getVisible()) {
        glColor3ub(list[index]->getR(), list[index]->getG(), list[index]-   >getB());
    } else {
        glColor3ub(0, 0, 0);
    }

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
        glVertex2i(marginLeft        , marginTop         ); // A
        glVertex2i(marginLeft + wQuad, marginTop         ); // B
        glVertex2i(marginLeft + wQuad, marginTop + hQuad); // D
        glVertex2i(marginLeft        , marginTop + hQuad); // C     
    glEnd();
}

void display2(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    for (int p = 0; p < length; p++) {
        createQuad(p);
    }   

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void init() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glOrtho(0, 905, 720, 0, -0.5f, 0.5f);
    glViewport(0, 0, 905, 720);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();   
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    __in  HINSTANCE hInstance,
    __in  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    __in  LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    __in  int nCmdShow
) {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    // Initialize the library
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    // Create the window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(905, 720, "Color Game", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); 

    init();

    // Create list...
    createList();
    char *myargv[1];
    int myargc = 1;
    myargv[0] = strdup("ColorGame");    

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glutInit(&myargc, myargv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
        glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
        glutDisplayFunc(display2);
        // display2();
        // glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Exception error]

The error is in this line:

```
glutDisplayFunc(display2);
```

If I put only display2(); works, but I need put glutDisplayFunc(display2); because after I need to treat a mouse event with this line glutMouseFunc(mouse); If I put glutMouseFunc(mouse); shows the same error.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I tried to use the debugger, I found the line "glutDisplayFunc(display2);" of the problem, but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Use GLUT xor GLFW.  And edit in a [mcve].

Comment: How to make a [mcve]?  Click on that link.  (It's not verifiable, because it won't compile, as we don't have Rect.h, and you've got at least one typo.  It's not minimal, as there's a lot in here that doesn't cause the crash.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GLUT xor GLFW.  They're both application frameworks that want sole control of your event loop and can't be used simultaneously.  Pick *one* and stick with it.

Example using GLUT (had to guess at `Rect`'s implementation):

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

const int rows = 40;
const int cols = 20;
const int length = rows * cols;
int width = 905;
int height = 720;

class Rect
{
public:
    Rect()
        : mVisible( rand() % 100 < 80 )
        , mR( rand() % 255 )
        , mG( rand() % 255 )
        , mB( rand() % 255 )
    {
    }

    bool getVisible() { return mVisible; }
    unsigned char getR() { return mR; }
    unsigned char getG() { return mG; }
    unsigned char getB() { return mB; }

private:
    bool mVisible;
    unsigned char mR;
    unsigned char mG;
    unsigned char mB;
};

Rect* list[length];

void createList()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        list[i] = new Rect();
    }
}

void createQuad(int index)
{
    int wQuad = (width / 20) - 5;
    int hQuad = 12;
    int margin = 5;
    int marginTop = (index / 20) * (hQuad + margin) + margin;
    int marginLeft = (index % 20) * (wQuad + margin) + margin;

    if( list[index]->getVisible() )
    {
        glColor3ub
            (
            list[index]->getR(),
            list[index]->getG(),
            list[index]->getB()
            );
    }
    else
    {
        glColor3ub(0, 0, 0);
    }

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
    glVertex2i( marginLeft        , marginTop         ); // A
    glVertex2i( marginLeft + wQuad, marginTop         ); // B
    glVertex2i( marginLeft + wQuad, marginTop + hQuad ); // D
    glVertex2i( marginLeft        , marginTop + hQuad ); // C     
    glEnd();
}

void display2(void)
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();   
    glOrtho(0, 905, 720, 0, -0.5f, 0.5f);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();   

    for (int p = 0; p < length; p++)
    {
        createQuad(p);
    }   

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("ColorGame");
    createList();
    glutDisplayFunc(display2);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up glut and glfw which is a bad idea. You should read the documentation of the libraries online. If you take this code out of the loop:

```
    glutInit(&myargc, myargv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutDisplayFunc(display2);
```

Delete glfw* and add this line:

```
    glutMainLoop();
```

Then it should work.